# Extract building footprints using a Normalized Digital Surface Model on eCognition

Tags: dem, ecognition, footprint

I have created a normalized Digital Surface Model (nDSM) by subtracting DEM from DSM. I have set a threshold value of 2 meters in order to eliminate objects such as shrubs, cars etc. Is there any methodology that differentiates buildings from trees using nDSM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Software can derive building footprints from imagery?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53238/which-software-can-derive-building-footprints-from-imagery)